# Why dialogflow v2 return" Webhook call failed. Error: UNAVAILABLE"?

Tags: python, flask, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am just using Dialogflow v2 and python for calling webhook .I always recieve this error  "Webhook call failed. Error: UNAVAILABLE."I am using flask ,ngrok,dialogflow .despite, I used dialogflow v1 and everything was fine. But with this change there at the level of dialogflow(migration to v2) my old chatbot suspended and when I try to add a new chatbot it shows me that error.For any chatbot I am trying to use dialogflow v2 it show me the same error  "Webhook call failed" and it does not show me webhook's response and it doesn't call the webhook for some reasons.
[fulfilment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sISda.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhGud.png)[RAW API RESPONSE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diQ1O.png)[my code flask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qPtJ.png)

could you help me please!
thanks for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

V2 is not backward compatible so the JSON payload sent from DialogFlow to your webhook is different now, and your code needs to be updated accordingly